# show loading gif until script has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display a loader icon gif until the script is totally loaded, is it possible?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="loading.gif">
```

I think it is necessary to use jquery. but I do not know how to do. could someone help me?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Chances are that Google's hosted jquery library is going to load at least as fast, if not faster, than wherever your code is hosted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Display image `<img src="loading.gif">`
2. On dom-ready remove element.

   `$(document).ready(function () {
       $('img').remove();
   })`

Answer (score 1):

Can be done even without jQuery:

```
<img id="loading" src="loading.gif">
<script onload="javascript:document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none'" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use this function which loads a script and fires a callback. In your callback, you hide the gif.

```
function loadScript( url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement( "script" )
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if(script.readyState) {  //IE
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
          script.onreadystatechange = null;
          callback();
        }
      };
    } else {  //Others
      script.onload = function() {
        callback();
      };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( script );
  }
```

So, in your HTML place your gif showing up initially. And, add this code at your onload function:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function(){
     loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js', function(){
        $('.gif-selector').hide();
     })
   }
</script>
```

Edit: This is a more complex solution than others provided, maybe if your goal is something pretty simple you should use some of the others. Still, this function works great and I have used it in many of my projects. It's best thing is that you can chose to load the script whenever you want to